# Strange behaviour with Zombie Objects for a project that mixes ARC and NON-ARC classes: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie, gmgridview

I have a big problem in my application and I'm wondering how to resolve it. I've searched a lot in SO but I cannot find a valid solution. Here the scenario I'm working on.

I have a NON-ARC application and I'm using a bunch of ARC classes within it. These classes belong to [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView). These classes have been added to the project with `-fobjc-arc` directive.

This is the code I'm using (for the sake of simplicity I added only key parts).

*Memory management section*

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [gmGridView setActionDelegate:nil];
    [gmGridView setDataSource:nil];
    [gmGridView release];    

    [super dealloc];
}
```

*ViewDidLoad section*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSInteger topBottomSpacing = 20;
    NSInteger leftRifghtSpacing = 75;
    NSInteger itemSpacing = 5;

    UIView* mainView = [self view];

    GMGridView* gridView = [[[GMGridView alloc] initWithFrame:mainView.bounds] autorelease];    
    gridView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    gridView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
    gridView.style = GMGridViewStyleSwap;
    gridView.itemSpacing = itemSpacing;
    gridView.minEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topBottomSpacing, leftRifghtSpacing, topBottomSpacing, leftRifghtSpacing);
    gridView.centerGrid = NO;
    gridView.actionDelegate = self;
    gridView.dataSource = self;    
    [mainView addSubview:gridView];

    [self setGmGridView:gridView]; // retain policy
}
```

*DataSource section*

```
- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    CGSize size = [self GMGridView:gridView sizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];

    GMGridViewCell *cell = [gridView dequeueReusableCell];    
    if (!cell) {

        cell = [[[GMGridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)] autorelease];

        InternalView *view = [[[InternalView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)] autorelease];
        cell.contentView = view;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

When I'm using Zombie Objects, the application works well. No errors. But when I disable Zombie Objects the application crashes **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** in `main` method. This is quite strange for me since if Zombies are enabled, I would see a detail of that error that happens in `main`.

The things I'm not pretty sure are the `autorelease` calls in the code, but I think that If I don't put the objects in an autorelease pool they will leak.

```
GMGridView* gridView = [[[GMGridView alloc] initWithFrame:mainView.bounds] autorelease];

cell = [[[GMGridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)] autorelease];
```

Investigating a bit I found that if I comment `[gmGridView release]` in `dealloc` method, the app stops to crash. So what does this mean? If I don't call `release`, will the `gmGridView` leak?

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I added some code in `- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index` method. I forgot to add it the first time.

The `dealloc` method of `InternalView` (of type `UIView`) seems the root of the problem. Here the code.

```
- (void)dealloc
{    
    [addButton release]; // it's added to self addSubview, it has also a retain policy
    [imageView release]; // it's added to detView addSubview, it has also a retain policy
    [detView release]; // it's added to self addSubview, it has also a retain policy

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Commenting `[detView release]`, the crash goes away.

Comment: Have you tried to run "Analyze" on you project? Also, adding "All exceptions" breakpoint might help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes. The thing strange to me is that when zombie are enabled, no crash occurs.

Comment: There might be external conditions like Memory Warning, which trigger your exception. Does the exception happen every time you run the app without zombies?

Comment: Yes, it does. I added an edit to explain in more detail since I forgot to insert a key part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex_Addicted,

Judging from your code, we are looking at MRR code (i.e. non-ARC). If it was ARC, you could not have the [super dealloc], the -release nor -autorelease.

Is that what you intend? If so, then you have an early deallocation. I recommend that you convert this class to ARC. ARC, along with the static analyzer, will find early deallocation problems and handle them.

Andrew

Comment: + 1 for your support. Yes it is. Thanks for the advice. I will try.